# How do I use Capistrano with a server that is behind a firewall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, portforwarding

I have a bit of a situation.  I've consumed about fourty-eleven different tutorials/books/videos on Capistrano, and none of them touch on out-of-the-norm cases.  They all assume straightforward setups -- which, in my experience, is rarely the case.

Basically my situation is as follows:

1) I am developing the application on a system at home

2) My goal is to run the application on a server at the office running behind the company router.  I have all the appropriate ports (21,22,80,3000,etc) forwarded to the machine so all is well as far as outside communication.

3)  I'm using GIT for version control, and I PUSH my updates to the server itself.

My confusion comes in two areas:

1)  How do I identify all the appropriate roles in the Capistrano recipe?  Do I base them on the external IP or the internal?

2)  How do I tell Capistrano to look locally (instead of trying to bounce out) on the same machine for the GIT repository?  Of course, this assumes that Capistrano does *anything at all* from the server.

NOTE:  One of the big issues I'm facing is the fact that none of the machines in the office can access the main IP from inside the network -- supposedly a protection from DOS and various other troubles -- so if for some reason the server needs to pretend the information is on an external machine when it's really local, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at the ':deploy_via' command; specifically 'copy':

http://www.capify.org/index.php/Understanding_Deployment_Strategies

Consider your home computer as remote, and the server as local, and this takes a local copy for the deployment.